# Is firebase user uid safe from a security perspective to use in "shared" links?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am storing the users uid (who log into my app) in my firebase database. I hope this approach is correct.

I'm now thinking of using this uid so if users want to share something in their app it'll create a link like `myapp.com/uid/data` for example. and then when someone else accesses this link, it'll make a call to firebase to get all the relevant data under the correct uid.

however, that means that person A could see person B's shared url and thus see what their uid is. I'm wonder if this is a safe practice or if there is a better way to be able to do this? of course I could randomly generate a link but then that leaves me with the issue of not being able to easily access the correct data in the firebase database as I have no reference point

could an attacker access firebase data with this random uid? even if my security rules are locked down to be

```
    "users": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
     }
```

Comment: It is safe to share the UID of a user with other users, as long as your app never allows operations based on another user's UID.

Comment: perfect, thanks Frank. I shall use it with no fears then